# How to get multple choice readio button in table cell in visual force?

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

I want to get all my radio button in  cell. Like following image

[image]

but i am getting like this

[image]

I tried to put  in  tag but i did not work. Please following code which i am using to achieve this and suggest.
Thanks.

```
<tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td colspan="2">The objectives were defined clearly by the faculty at the beginning of the programme</td>
    <td colspan="5"><apex:selectRadio value="{!c.The_objectives_were_defined_clearly_by_t__c}">
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Strongly Disagree" itemValue="5"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Disagree" itemValue="4"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Somewhat Agree" itemValue="3"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Agree" itemValue="2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Strongly Agree" itemValue="1"/>
 </apex:selectRadio></td>

  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apex:selectRadio` tag generates a new table element by itself. Each radio button puts into the table cell `td`. So if you want to see the table border or put some styling to it you have to define a style class name:

```
<style>
.mySelect td{
    border:1px solid;
}

<apex:selectRadio value="{!yourVariable}" styleClass="mySelect">
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Strongly Disagree" itemValue="5"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Disagree" itemValue="4"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

The code generated will looks like this:

```
<table role="presentation" class="mySelect">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="j_id0:j_id4:j_id6" id="j_id0:j_id4:j_id6:0" value="5"><label for="j_id0:j_id4:j_id6:0"> Strongly Disagree</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="j_id0:j_id4:j_id6" id="j_id0:j_id4:j_id6:1" value="4"><label for="j_id0:j_id4:j_id6:1"> Disagree</label>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Good answer but do you know what to do if you want to show each value in a new row? one under the other one and so on?

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap it up in an outputpanel.

Comment: Can you elaborate and show how that works?